# Apache2 mpm-itk Issues with PHP & vBulletin

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache2, vbulletin, linode

I've spent a long time on this without much luck, so here I am.

SERVER DETAILS OF NOTE:

```
Linode 1024 (1GB RAM)
Apache2
Ubuntu 10.04
MySQL 5.1
PHP 5.3
vBulletin 4.2.0
mpm-itk
mod_php
mod_pagespeed
```

PHP Memory Limit 32M

All images loaded from a CDN on an external domain (Rackspace Cloud Files).

apache2.conf directives of note:

```
Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers           1
    MinSpareServers        3
    MaxSpareServers        6
    ServerLimit           24
    MaxClients            24
    MaxRequestsPerChild 3000
</IfModule>
```

These setting are recommended here:
http://library.linode.com/troubleshooting/memory-networking

PROBLEM:

I'm at a loss to uncover why this server might be having issues. Traffic is fairly low. At most 4-5 simultaneous users online at any one time.

It runs perfectly for some time and processes seem steady, then processes fork, but aren't released and the server stops responding. I wondered whether this was an out of memory issue, but 1GB should be plenty for this kind of traffic. Running top sorted by memory consumption shows nothing too odd and plenty of memory available. No swap usage of any note.

At times there are lots of forked processes, but that's to be expected. I'd expect the above settings to limit them from getting out of control. Reducing them simply introduces 501 errors, which while better than the timeout alternative, isn't much better.

I read that reducing the PHP memory limit can help, but going as low as 32M didn't help me.

Can anyone help me troubleshoot what might be happening here?

Comment: So far, I seem to have fixed this in the interim with
`KeepAlive Off`
I'll post an answer once I've tested this for a decent amount of time and added some other tuning tweaks.